# How to change a cells fill color based on if the previous cell contains certain text?

Tags: excel

How to change one cell fill color based on the text of the previous cell.

I know that I need to use conditional formatting along with using a formula to determine which cell to format, but I just can't figure out what formula to use.

Comment: It is not clear what tool or application you are using. Is it Excel? Is it Lotus 1-2-3? Please provide more details so people will know how to help.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the condition, you can use Conditional Formatting on the Home Tab and set a rule
under **Use a formula to determine which cells to format** there you can specify if for example `=A1>5` Format it to Fill Green then select to what cells you want this rule to be applied.
You can find more information here: [How to create rules with Conditional Formatting](https://www.got-it.ai/solutions/excel-chat/excel-tutorial/conditional-formatting/conditionally-format-a-cell).

Comment: That does make sense. But lets say they're not numbers, instead text. How do I do that? Like im looking for certain words to fill the next cell a certain color

Comment: create the list you want to work with for example Low will be red and High green then go to `Conditional Formatting | Highlight Cells Rules | Text that Contains` and create a rule for Low and one for High after that just go to Manage Rules and select where you want it to be applied. It should do the trick.